# Transfer Boom Beach account to another Android device

Tags: google-account, google-play-games

I had Boom Beach on my phone and I have leveled up a lot. Now I wanted to download it and continue to play it on my tablet. I thought I had signed into my Google Play account on my Boom Beach on my phone, but I hadn't. When I went to sign in on my tablet, it saved the new game on my tablet instead of transferring the game info I had on my phone.

How to sign out of Boom Beach on my tablet so I can sign into it on my phone?

Comment: Try to follow [this article](http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-2347918/transfer-accounts-android-devices-boom-beach.html). According to that, if you haven't upgraded your HQ to lv. 4, you may have a chance to reload from the old account. Try uninstall-reinstalling the game on the tablet.